# Python Parsing with js script src

Tags: javascript, python, parsing

I am trying to parse [Ekonika](https://ekonika.ru/catalog/view/en00173cn22black22z), but when I am doing basic requests get, it gives me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 
    <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />
    <script src="/__qrator/qauth_utm_v2.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
 
</body>
</html>
```

I cant really get where information is? When I am adding "/__qrator/qauth_utm_v2.js" to the link  it says The page is forbidden.

Can you please advice the right way to parse it?

Comment: `https://ekonika.ru/__qrator/qauth_utm_v2.js`

Comment: Thank you for answer, but when I go to this link, I do not see the information that original link provides

Comment: It's not possible with requests. You have to use selenium